# jstree - adding child nodes which themselves contain children

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I have some code in which I need the ability to add child nodes to a jstree which themselves contain children. The below code adds a 'child2' node correctly to 'child1' but ignores the child3 data. Any help much appreciated. Code follows:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.jstree.com/v.1.0rc2/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.jstree.com/v.1.0rc2/jquery.jstree.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(function () {
        $("#tree").jstree({ 
            "json_data" : {
                "data" : [
                    { 
                        "data" : "parent", 
                        "attr" : { "id" : "root.id" }, 
                        "children" : [ { "data" : "child1",
                                         "attr" : { "id" : "child1.id" },
                                         "children" : [ ] }
                                     ]
                    },
                ]
            },
            "plugins" : [ "themes", "json_data", "crrm" ]
        });
    });
    $("#add").click(function() {
        $("#tree").jstree("create", $("#child1\\.id"), "inside",
                { "data" : "child2", "attr" : { "id" : "child2.id" },
                  "children" : [ { "data" : "child3", "attr" : { "id" : "child3.id" }, "children": [ ] } ] },
                          function() { alert("added"); }, true);
    });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="tree" name="tree"></div>

<input type="button" id="add" value="add" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Perhaps this isn't possible? I'd presuemd the create function was implemented to recurse over children, but maybe not... Going to take a look at the source...

Comment: i had the same problem how could you solved it?

Answer (score 1):

First off, that's not valid json with the last comma inside the last bracket. Take that off:

```
[
   {
        "data" : "parent",
        "attr" : {
            "id" : "root.id"
        },
        "children" : [
            {
                "data" : "child1",
                "attr" : {
                    "id" : "child1.id"
                },
                "children" : [ ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Also, as of version 3.0 or perhaps before you can simply just insert a new node with json. Recursion is no longer needed.

I created json like so, which creates a folder called income and puts many text children underneath it but also those could be folders just like the parent with more content. See my function below which inserts this folder into the parent with all it's children:

```
{
    "text" : "Income",
        "id" : "_folder_income",
        "state" : {
            "opened" : true 
        },
        "children" : [
        {
            "text" : "$125,000 - $150,000",
            "state" : {
                "selected" : true 
            },
            "icon" : "jstree-file",
            "id" : "6017897162332"
        },
        {
            "text" : "$150,000 - $250,000",
            "state" : {
                "selected" : false 
            },
            "icon" : "jstree-file",
            "id" : "6017897374132"
        },
        {
            "text" : "$250,000 - $350,000",
            "state" : {
                "selected" : false 
            },
            "icon" : "jstree-file",
            "id" : "6017897397132"
        },
        {
            "text" : "$350,000 - $500,000",
            "state" : {
                "selected" : false 
            },
            "icon" : "jstree-file",
            "id" : "6017897416732"
        },
        {
            "text" : "Over $500,000",
            "state" : {
                "selected" : false 
            },
            "icon" : "jstree-file",
            "id" : "6017897439932"
        },
        {
            "text" : "$30,000 - $40,000",
            "state" : {
                "selected" : false 
            },
            "icon" : "jstree-file",
            "id" : "6018510070532"
        },
        {
            "text" : "$100,000 - $125,000",
            "state" : {
                "selected" : false 
            },
            "icon" : "jstree-file",
            "id" : "6018510083132"
        },
        {
            "text" : "$40,000 - $50,000",
            "state" : {
                "selected" : false 
            },
            "icon" : "jstree-file",
            "id" : "6018510087532"
        },
        {
            "text" : "$75,000 - $100,000",
            "state" : {
                "selected" : false 
            },
            "icon" : "jstree-file",
            "id" : "6018510100332"
        },
        {
            "text" : "$50,000 - $75,000",
            "state" : {
                "selected" : false 
            },
            "icon" : "jstree-file",
            "id" : "6018510122932"
        }
    ]
}
```

This same json could also be used to fill a parent folder on tree instance:

```
/**
 * inserts a new node (json object returned from url) into an existing node (parentNodeId), for the div ud in jsTreeName which is
 * an instanced jstree.
 * @param string jsTreeName  {name of an instanced tree}
 * @param string url  {returns json}
 * @param string parentNodeId {string of the parent node id}
 */
function insertUrlIntoNode(jsTreeName, url, parentNodeId) {
  var nodeTree = getSynchronousJson(url);
  var tree = $('#'+jsTreeName).jstree(true);
  tree.deselect_all();
  var sel = tree.create_node(parentNodeId, nodeTree);
  //tree.deselect_all();
  //tree.select_node(sel);  //optionally you could select the new node after insersion
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see from the source, "create" function doesn't support creating multi-level tree at once. The method that gets called doesn't use and check the `children` attribute on passed data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it yourself, something like that :

```
                var recursivelyCreate = function (node, parentNodeId) {
                    tree.jstree("create", $("#"+parentNodeId), "inside",  node, function() {}, true);
                    if(node.children){
                        $.each(node.children, function(i, child){
                            recursivelyCreate(child, node.attr.id);
                        });
                    }
                };
                recursivelyCreate(rootNodeYouWantToInsert,nodeParentId);
```